# Object orientation + decoupling: Add Knowledge/Method to Object or other class?

Tags: class, oop, decoupling

While working on a `Symfony 2` based WebApp project and I came up with a general OOP question:

A WebApp project based on the `Symfony` Framework is sperated into different `Bundles`. This is basically just an alias for `Library`, `Assembly`, etc. in other Frameworks: Code/Classes that belong together somehow are organized within the same `Bundle`.

To be re-usable, different `Bundles` should be (more or less) independent from each other.

My WebApp Project contains (beside other) the follow two bundles:

- **AppBundle**: Containing the core model and layout, etc.
- **ShopBundle**: Containing all classes and code necessary to purchase subscriptions (access to the WebApp)

The `User` class, that represents the entity of an logged in user, is stored in the `AppBundle`.

Now I need a new method, that tells me, whether a users has placed a purchases or not.

**Big question is: Where should I implement this method?**

**Solution 1:** Add `hasPurchases()` to `User` class

This sounds reasonable, since the question "Does user XY has purchases" is of course a question to user XY. BUT: If the `User` class implements this method, the class has to know/use the `ShopBundle` and would thus be depended from this bundle. This would be a disadvantage, this I would like to avoid coupling between the bundles.

**Solution 2:** Implement `hasPurchases($user)` in some external class

To avoid any dependency of the `User` class from the `ShopBundle` I could move the method to some external class. The method would receive the `user` object as parameter and then check if there are any purchases for that user.

The advantage would be, that the `User` object still does not need to know anything about the `ShopBundle`. However I would just move the coupling problem to another class: Now the class XY that implements `hasPurchases($user)` needs to know both the `User` class and the `ShopBundle`.

So, what is the `correct` solution here?